# Current profile as condition in llama

Tags: automation, llama

Llama is a great tool, but I cannot figure out one (maybe) simple thing. I have a rule that sets the volume low at night (10pm - 6 am) and it works fine. Last night (9pm) I was at the cinema and selected the profile "silent". But at 10pm of course, llama set the profile to "low volume".

Is there a workaround a profile changes only when a certain profile is set (or not set)?

When the profile "silent" is set by another rule I set a llama-variable silence=1, and in the night-rule this variable is checked first. But when I set the profile manually, the variable-workaround doesn't work. I know I can lock profiles, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with *Llama* – but given it's similarity to *Tasker* obviously also for variables, you could try adding a profile setting `silence=1` whenever the profile is set to "silence", and reset that when the profile is left (with *Tasker*, there are "entry-tasks" and "exit-tasks", so this could be done definitely – not sure how *Llama* does that, hence just a comment for now). Please let us know whether that works, so I might make this an answer.

Comment: In Llama there are no "entry-tasks", that would be helpful. I'll try _Tasker_, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: To ease your start (and the search for tutorials etc), you might wish to take a look into my [Collection of Tasker Resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) (tutorials and documentation at the end of that page). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcuts to activate specific Llama Events can be placed on the home screen. Therefore create an Event (or use an existing one):

Name: Go Silent (or whatever you want)
Enabled: yes
Conditions: None
Actions:
     1. llama variable: silence=1
     2. Profile: Silent (can also use Advanced option to lock the profile for a fixed time e.g. 2 hours, so other events won't change it regardless of whether those other events check the silence variable. Note that that after this time elapses, it'll automatically switch back to the prvious profile)

Now that the event is defined, go to your Android home screen and put a Llama shortcut on it which will open a window listing the various Llama Profiles and Events, and select your Go Silent event. Now pressing the shortcut will activate the Silent profile and set silence=1 for testing by your other events.

Alternatively, rather than creating the Event first, just create the shortcut and select "Custom event actions" and this will drop you to limited a Llama Event creation screen that only allows a name and Actions to be defined (without conditions etc).

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use the profile lock. As that is what is intended for.

Go to the profile press the lock icon next to the profile you want to set,  then just select the length of time.

Also if you go to the same theater,  make a profile for that area for silent. Obviously if it uses the same tower as another area, you will have to add condition such as"and" or "or" to prevent conflicts.